# Does CloudSpanner support Fuzzy Search or Wild Card Search?

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

I'm doing research on CloudSpanner as part of a spike for work, and comparing it to BigTable/Elastic Search. My team wanted to find out whether or not CloudSpanner supports either FuzzySearch and/or WildCard query. I could find this neither in articles nor by viewing youtube live demos, and i can't access a demo/free trial either. I know that CloudSpanner utilizes NewSQL but I couldn't find anything on NewSQL supporting those either.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Spanner doesn't support FuzzySearch directly and as far as I know it does not support WildCard Queries directly.

the most similar things that it supports that can work for you are:

**Regular Expressions:**

With the function [REGEXP_CONTAINS](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/functions-and-operators#regexp_contains) with which you can perform queries with a regular expression that matches what you want. This allows to look for `[úuü]` looks for all the alternatives of u.

**LIKE Operator**

The like operator will allow you to match a section of a string. to see it documentation you can check it [here](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/functions-and-operators#comparison_operators)

If none of this alternatives work for you then i would suggest to do something like [this](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/fuzzy-searches-sql-server/)

Answer (score -2):

Yes, Cloud Spanner supports wild cards for some SQL queries (see documentation).

https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/query-syntax

Comment: this is not mentioned on the documentation

Comment: That is not true.  It supports wild card queries within SQL statements.

(e.g.) 

SELECT expression.*

SELECT *